# Mock Multiple derived Derived class in cpp - google mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a multiple derived class that inherit from basic class that looks like below and would like to mock all derived class.

Do i need to create a MockBase class or Do i need to repeat base class methods in every derived class mock objects ?

**Note:** I would to test Dervied1User & Dervied2User and hence would like to create MockDervied1 and MockDerived2.  Dervied1User has calls to the methods both in Dervied1 and base classes.

```
class base {
  base() { .. }
  virtual ~base(..) { ... }
  virtual bool method0(..) { ... }
  virtual bool method1(..) { ... }
  virtual void method2(..) { ... }
};

class Derived1 : public base {
  Derived1() { ... }
  virtual int method3(..) { ... }
  virtual int method4(..) { ... }
};

class Derived2 : public base() {
  Derived2() { ... }
  virtual int method5(..) { ... }
  virtual int method6(..) { ... }
};

class Derived3 : public base() {
  Derived2() { ... }
  virtual int method7(..) { ... }
  virtual int method8(..) { ... }
};

class Dervied1User {
 public:
  Dervied1User(std::unique_ptr<Derived1> d1_) : d1(std::move(d1_)) {}
    int method9(..) {...}
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Derived1> d1;
};

class Dervied2User {
    ....
}
```

Does the mock for derived class looks like this. ? Repeating the method0, method1, method2 in all the Derived class mocks .

```
class MockDerived1 : pubic Derived1 {
  MOCK_METHOD(method0, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method1, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method2, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method3, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method4, ....)
}

class MockDerived2 : pubic Derived2 {
  MOCK_METHOD(method0, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method1, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method2, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method5, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method6, ....)
}
```

Comment: You probably know this already, but for the benefit of other people landing here: mocking classes with non-pure virtual functions is error-prone in the first place because forgetting to mock a method will not be caught by the compiler. Normally, if such a class is going to be mocked, you really want to add an abstract interface root class that serves as the mock target as well as the type that gets passed around in the application code. It's also better design in general.

Comment: @Frank, I am new to google testing and not aware of the fact of have pure virtual functions. Thanks for letting me know.  I will surely consider refactoring my code in near future.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: Do nothing

If you don't need to intercept the calls to `base` during the testing of `Derived1`, then you don't have to do anything. None of the methods in question are pure virtual so not mocking them will just fallback to the base implementation. Obviously whether this is a possibility or not is highly contextual.

```
class MockDerived1 : public Derived1 {
  MOCK_METHOD(method3, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method4, ....)
};

class MockDerived2 : public Derived2 {
  MOCK_METHOD(method5, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method6, ....)
};
```

**N.B.** The fact that Option 1 is available to you at all is a code smell. You could be doing this accidentally when you would have wanted to mock a method, and the compiler would let you do it. If creating a `baseInterface` abstract base class that `base` inherits from is a possibility, I would seriously recommend it.

#### Option 2: Repeat the base mocks in each derived mock.

> Does the mock for derived class looks like this. ? Repeating the method0, method1, method2 in all the Derived class mocks .

```
class MockDerived1 : public Derived1 {
  MOCK_METHOD(method0, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method1, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method2, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method3, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method4, ....)
};

class MockDerived2 : public Derived2 {
  MOCK_METHOD(method0, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method1, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method2, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method5, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method6, ....)
};
```

Yep, this works just fine! It can be annoying and potentially error prone though. If you ever change `base`, you need to go and update every single derived mock class, which can be a massive chore in certain codebases.

**N.B.** Options 1 and 2 are not mutually exclusive, you can pick and choose which methods you need to mock as long as executing implementation in `base` during tests is ok.

#### Option 3: Use a macro

A fairly simple thing you can do to reduce duplication would be to create a macro that adds the mocks of `base` to any given subclass. One obvious advantage is that if `base` changes, you can just change the macro and all mocks will be updated at once. Google mock is already macro-centric, so it's one of those cases where they are not completely out of place:

```
#define MOCK_BASE_MEMBERS() \
    MOCK_METHOD(method0, ....) \
    MOCK_METHOD(method1, ....) \
    MOCK_METHOD(method2, ....) \
// end of macro

class MockDerived1 : public Derived1 {
  MOCK_BASE_MEMBERS()
  MOCK_METHOD(method3, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method4, ....)
};

class MockDerived2 : public Derived2 {
  MOCK_BASE_MEMBERS()
  MOCK_METHOD(method5, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method6, ....)
};

#undef MOCK_BASE_MEMBERS
```

#### Option 4: MockBase

Since you mention it in the question, let's discuss what a `MockBase` would entail.

There's a few different ways you could accomplish this, but only one is remotely viable.

Since you'd want your class hierarchy to look like `base -> Derived1 -> MockBase -> MockDerived1`,
it means that `MockBase` needs to inherit from a different base for each Dervied class. That's a job for templates:

```
template<typename T>
class MockBase : public T {
  MOCK_METHOD(method0, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method1, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method2, ....)
};

class MockDerived1 : public MockBase<Derived1> {
  MOCK_METHOD(method3, ....)
  MOCK_METHOD(method4, ....)
};
```

If you are completely allergic to macros, you might want to do this, but I personally find more convoluted than necessary.